# New kernel causes log in issues

Tags: grub2, kernel

I have recently become interested in the Linux kernel and wanted to compile it from source and run it on my system (16.04). I followed the instructions on

https://kernelnewbies.org/OutreachyfirstpatchSetup

and I was able to compile the kernel using the default config in Ubuntu. I also updated GRUB and restarted my system. Everyhting went fine until I came to the login screen and tried to log in. The system accepts my password but then immediately crashes and I am once again presented with the log in screen. I restarted my system and booted into the old kernel (4.8.0-58-generic).

Now I wonder, is it possible for me got get the system running properly under the new kernel? If not, how can I uninstall the new kernel and change GRUB so that it defaults to 4.8.0-58-generic?

Comment: That was a very bad way to install a kernel this way. Your issue is probably related to some proprietary video drivers that are not compatible with the new kernel. If you built and install a kernel using a normal way (using deb files) it would be much easier to uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am using the NVIDIA drivers so that might be the problem... This is literally the first time I try to install a kernel on my own so I don't know of any other way. How would you suggest installing a kernel and where can I find more info?

Comment: If you google by "Ubuntu compile install kernel", you will find a lot of relevant information.

Answer (score -1):

In uninstalling the new kernel you can simply

```
sudo apt-get remove <linux-image>
```

Or you can use synaptic package manager search for linux-image. A list of images will appear then you can delete the desired kernel.

Comment: No, not really, because it was compiled from source, not installed via APT. It makes a huge difference in this case.